# how to get props from component in my screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello guys I've created a star rating component and now I've added it in my screen. My question now is how to I get the component return value inside my screen to send it to the server on submit.

This is my component

```
export default class StarsRating extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            rating: this.props.rating || null,
            temp_rating: null
        }
    }

    rate(rating) {
        this.setState({
            rating: rating,
            temp_rating: rating
        });
    }

    render() {
        // This array will contain our star tags. We will include this
        // array between the view tag.
        let stars = [];
        // Loop 5 times
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            // Set the icon to filled stars
            let icon = "star-outline";
            // If ratings is lower, set the icon to unfilled stars
            if (this.state.rating >= i && this.state.rating != null) {
                icon = "star";
            }
            // Push the Icon tag in the stars array
            stars.push((
                <TouchableOpacity key={i} onPress={this.rate.bind(this, i)}>
                    <Icon
                        name={icon}
                        size={40}
                        color={colors.yellow}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity >
            ));
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                {stars}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

and in my screen I access it like this `<StarsRating />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option will be to pass `onChanged` function as a prop to Your component from screen (where You render it).

```
<StarsRating onChanged={(rating) => {
    // yourFunctionWithApiCall(rating)
    // axios.post() directly here 
}} />
```

In `StarsRating` Component You just need to add call to this function in `rate` method.

```
rate(rating) {
    this.setState({
        rating: rating,
        temp_rating: rating
    });

    // when You think that value should be saved to API call function passed with props
   this.props.onChanged(rating);
}
```

In general - pass this api communication function to your component as a props. Thanks to that You will can reuse it in another project when behaviour after rating change can be different.